# How to check email mailbox in min time?

Tags: python, email, verification

I am trying to verify emails which is over 70 lac. 
I am using the [this script](https://github.com/socomm/verify-email/blob/master/verify-email.py)

But it is taking approx 2-3 min for one email. Since I try other code, but all are using the same method. So I am thinking all will take the approx same time.

Is there any fast way to doing this?

COde that I am using:

```
for file in /home/itstym/Desktop/email_database/*
do
   echo $file
    while read in; 
    do 
      ./verify-email.py "$in"; 
    done < $file
done
```

[./verify-email code is here](https://github.com/socomm/verify-email/blob/master/verify-email.py)

sample file input:

```
jayasur@aol.com
jayatca@aol.com
jayatch@aol.com
jayatdt@aol.com
jayatee@aol.com
jayatgv@aol.com
jayatil@aol.com
jayatkd@aol.com
jayatki@aol.com
```

**EDIT:**
A strange thing I have noticed that when I am running the cmd like that
`./verify-email.py "email"` it is giving the response within second but when I am running it in the loop(using above script), it is taking too much time.

Comment: Welcome.   Please take the tour at https://unix.stackexchange.com/Tour so you can see how this works.  We'll  need to see the actual code in order to attract useful ansers.

Comment: The script you refer in your post doesn't check for an incoming e-mail. It sends (partially performs an SMTP command sequence to send an e-mail) a new e-mail instead. Are you checking for e-mails or for e-mail addressess?

Comment: @Serge yup, it is sending email to check whether email mailbox exists or not. Moreover, I have updated my question, now It is more clear what I want

Answer (score 0):

The method you are trying to employ is not reliable at all.

Some servers,  would accept the envelope (all together `MAIL FROM`, `RCPT TO` and `DATA` commands) completely without any signs that destination address does not exist. Some servers may perform DNS checks if the source IP is a legitimate IP address to accept e-mails from 'MAIL FROM' address. These checks may induce delay during `MAIL FROM` command processing or be performed later. 
To combat spam some servers may introduce a delay for command processing which is based on prior history of the SMTP session(s) of originating IP.

It is all implementation dependent.

Comment: is there any way to do it in free?

Comment: But then why it is giving response very fast when I am trying to one email?

Comment: @Ankur_009 No, there is no free nor easy way.

Comment: @Ankur_009 because when you first connects the server may assume that you are legitimate sender and then adjust its behavior based on your actions

Comment: and what is the difficult way?

Comment: @Ankur_009 Send a message to an address and ask the recipient to confirm in response that address does exist.

Comment: but this way also takes too much time, and it depends on the recipient.

Comment: @Ankur_009 you will find the cost less cheese only in mouse trap and being a second mouse only.